# Notes about your changes

Tags: control-panel

On a CP edit entry page there is a box for 'Notes about your changes'.
I have entered text in there and saved the entry, but it doesn't seem show up anywhere. How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my answer I am going to assume you are running Craft 3.

Notes are displayed in the sidebar:

[image]

When viewing the "Current" version of an entry, you can see the notes in the sidebar from when that entry was **last saved**.

If you go back through the version history of an entry, the notes in the sidebar will change to the notes left from the **previous version of that entry**.

You can also add notes to a draft version of an entry:

[image]

Once the draft has been published, the draft version will now become the "Current" version, and the notes from the draft should show in the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that it was showing underneath the Updated at: I was looking in the changes box. I had been looking for a way to leave a permanent note about how the Summary field should be formatted.

Comment: Without using a plugin, I don't believe there is a way to leave permanent messages. Maybe you could include this info in the instructions for the summary field? That's what I do for my projects.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is that this is just for one entry in a section with many other entries. I may need to create a new section (perhaps make it a single) just for this. It's part of other general information entries but the summary is used to populate a few pop-up explainers. I didn't want to duplicate it or hard code it into the template and then have one version updated and not the other.